# Setting font size for markdown inline in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter

I would like to set default font size and font type via code in line within a python notebook.

For example, I use this to set plot size defaults:

```
params = {'legend.fontsize': 'x-large','figure.figsize': (15, 10),'axes.labelsize': 'x-large','axes.titlesize':'x-large',
         'xtick.labelsize':'x-large','ytick.labelsize':'x-large'}
pylab.rcParams.update(params)
```

I use this to set window width defaults

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.container { width:100% !important; }</style>"))
```

Is there a command that lets me set default markdown font to Arial size 24? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MarkdownCell.render` can be patched to render markdown cells to a specified font size.

Dump the snippet below in a code cell and run.

```
from IPython.core.display import Javascript, display

def set_markdown_font():
    javascript = """
    var _render = IPython.MarkdownCell.prototype.render;

    if (_render.decorator === undefined) {
      IPython.MarkdownCell.prototype.render = function () {
        this.element.find('.rendered_html p').css('font-size', '30px');
        return _render.apply(this, arguments);
      }
      IPython.MarkdownCell.prototype.render.decorator = true;
    }
    """
    display(Javascript(data=javascript))

set_markdown_font()
```

**Edit**

You can also target HTMLElement having `.rendered_html` class and style them appropriately. I prefer this better (CSS over JS).

```
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML
display(HTML("<style>.rendered_html { font-size: 30px; }</style>"))
```

Comment: That you Oluwafemi! Worked! I prefer the second solution as it's much cleaner.